# How to show price and variation price for logged in users only in woocommerce?

Tags: logging, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a woocommerce in my wp site, and I need to show the prices and variation prices only when the user loggin. I have this code, but only work with the price, not with variation price...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');

function members_only_price($price){

if(is_user_logged_in() ){
return $price;
}

else {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
return 'Only <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
  }

}
```